# Python print statement prints address instead of value

Tags: python

This is the code which I have did

```
from itertools import product
lst1=list(map(int,input().split()))
lst2=list(map(int,input().split()))
l3=product(lst1,lst2)
```

Input:

```
1 2
2 3
```

Output:

```
<itertools.product object at 0x7f02bdedb500>
```

Output that I want:

```
(1, 3) (1, 4) (2, 3) (2, 4)
```

I have tried adding parentheses, brackets and also tried to store the value in a variable and printed it. I still couldn't able to get that output. I don't want the output as a list, the expected output is shown above.

Comment: Try Like this l3= list(product(lst1,lst2)), then print l3.

Comment: `itertools.product` produces an iterable, just like `range`.  To force the result to a list, just use `list(iterable)`, where `iterable` is any iterable, in your case `product(lst1,lst2)`.

Comment: just add ```print(list(l3))```

Comment: so just iterate over each element and print with `end flag` as  `print(i, end=' ')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`product(lst1,lst2)` returns a `itertools.product` object just use `map function` to update internal tuple 1st index item or iterate though each element.

**So use map function and update each tuple by 1 using lambda function :**

```
l3= list(map(lambda i: (i[0], i[-1]+1), product(lst1,lst2)))
print(l3)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
```

---

Problem with this output is that it is string representation of `list object` so the best way is to go with this method.
**So use iterate though this iterable object :**

```
for i in l3:
    i = list(i)
    i[-1] += 1
    print(tuple(i), end=' ')
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
(1, 3) (1, 4) (2, 3) (2, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert or cast it to list, it works.

```
from itertools import product
lst1=list(map(int,input().split()))
lst2=list(map(int,input().split()))
l3=list(product(lst1,lst2))
```

Answer (score 0):

"itertools.product" returns a generator, to get the list output you need :

```
list(l3)
```

However, not sure where you got your values from, I got :

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate l3 to get the desired output:

```
for i in l3:
    print(i, end=" ")
```